# dynamically adding html form elements and updated data gets reset

Tags: javascript

So the below code dynamically adds html form elements using javascript.
The problem is that if I add new html form elements, then update it with what I want (i.e. type in abc) and then click on add another it wipes what I'd previously typed in and resets it back to its original text.

For example:

Click on "Add more data"

I then change "First Name" to John, "Last name" to Doe.

I then click on "Add more data" again and John has been reset to "First name" and Doe has been reset to "Last name".

How do I fix this?

```
<script>
var x = 1;

function add() {
var fooId = "foo";

for (i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");

//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", fooId+x+i);
element.setAttribute("name", fooId+x+i);
element.setAttribute("id", fooId+x+i);

if(i==1){
       element.setAttribute("value", "First name");
 }
if(i==2){
      element.setAttribute("value", "Last name");

}
if(i==3){
    element.setAttribute("value", "age");

}          
var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
foo.appendChild(element);
foo.innerHTML += ' ';

}
    i++;            
var br = document.createElement("br");
foo.appendChild(br);

x++;

}
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<center>

<form id="form" name="form" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" id="foo01" name="foo01" value="first name"> 

<input type="text" id="foo02" name="foo02" value="last name"/>  
<input type="text" id="foo03" name="foo03" value="age"> 
<br>
<span id="fooBar"></span>

<FORM>

<INPUT type="button" value="Add more data" onclick="add()"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</center>
</FORM>

</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange but this line:

```
foo.innerHTML += ' ';
```

causes the issue, when removing it , everything works fine.
You can use this instead:

```
var space = document.createTextNode(" ");
foo.appendChild(space);
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Jk8Jm/3/